# Retrofit2 - Requests are always status 404 and the response null

Tags: android, retrofit2

I saw 3 other SO posts regarding this but the solutions didn't work. Every endpoint is returned as `status code 404` and the response is null in retrofit2. This is my retrofit implementation:

**RetrofitService:**

```
//code setup for HTTP client for Retrofit goes here
......
......
public static void initRetrofit() {
        builder =
                new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
          .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(initGson()));
}
```

**BuildConfig**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://MY_SERVICE.azurewebsites.net\""
        }
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix ".staging"
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://MY_SERVICE.azurewebsites.net\""
        }
}
```

**Endpoints:**

```
public interface APIServices {

    @POST("api/users/register.json")
    Call<HttpResponse<Auth>> register(@Body RegisterData data);

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Other SO threads suggested to remove the `/` of `/api` from the `/api/users/register.json`, which I did and yet no change in the response.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't setup HTTP client for your `Retrofit` object. Try to use `OkHttpClient` for this.

```
public static void initRetrofit() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(Config.HTTP_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .readTimeout(Config.HTTP_READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(Config.HTTP_READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();

        builder =
                new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                        .client(client)
          .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(initGson()));
}
```

Plus, check your API address - try to use some service (e.g. Postman) for this: enter your address (from your code it is: 'http://MY_SERVICE.azurewebsites.netapi/users/register.json').

Comment: These have been setup, I didnt include that in the answer. It was to be assumed, sorry I didnt mention that :D

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit2 base url should end with a trailing slash. Try adding it:

```
buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://MY_SERVICE.azurewebsites.net/\""
```

Comment: So add a `/` to the base url and remove the `/` from the `/api/users` endpoint?

Comment: Yes, that's the convention